# How would I set the background colour of a Xamarin Forms Android Picker popup

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, picker, custom-renderer

I am trying to set the background colour for the popup that appears when you click a picker in xamarin forms. However, the background colour that changes is for the object that you click to display the popup rather than the popup itself as shown below

[image: Picker with background colour set to red]
[image: Picker popup with background colour still set to white]

I have tried to resolve this using a custom renderer, with Control.BackgroundTintList, which has worked in similar situations, but this appears to not do anything. Another thing I tried was using styles.xml as is possible with DatePicker, but I had no luck with this either as Picker doesn't have a dialog apparently.

Googling provides a lot of tutorials on how to do this for IOS only, by using a custom renderer, but I couldn't find anything for android that actually changed the background colour.

Any advice would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create another view with a ListView that when an item gets selected, it closes and returns the result. This way you could use it on every platfor and modify the background color, and the color of the options and everything.

If you do this, yo can do it in anotherpage and just use a PushModalAsync, or use an AbsoluteLayout or GridLayout to show the other element

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom picker pop-up, and then you will be able to style it in much more ways and it should work on both iOS and Android. Here's the simple example of what you can do:

**XAML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="listInPopUp.MainPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button Text="Display Prompt!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>


        <ContentView x:Name="popupView" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="220" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                    <ContentView Padding="12, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Text="Title" />
                    </ContentView>
                    <ListView x:Name="OptionList" ItemSelected="OnItemClicked" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <Button Text="Cancel" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16"  BackgroundColor="Aqua" TextTransform="None" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**C#**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace listInPopUp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyList.Add("Option 1");
            MyList.Add("Option 2");
            MyList.Add("Option 3");
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            //This will show the pop up
            popupView.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void OnItemClicked(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            popupView.IsVisible = false;
            var item = e.SelectedItem as String;
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (item == "Option 1")
                {
                    //Do something
                }
                // etc.
            }
        }
        private void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupView.IsVisible = false;
            //Your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you something a popup like this (With `BackgroundColor` of `StackLayout` and `Button` you can change the background of pop-up. Also you can style other things):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom renderer to define a custom Dialog.

**Custom renderer:**

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(AndroidPickerRenderer))]
  namespace App10.Droid
{
public class AndroidPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    private Context context;
    AlertDialog listDialog;
    string[] items;

    public AndroidPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.Click += Control_Click;
        }
    }

    private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker model = Element;
        items = model.Items.ToArray();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
        builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (s, a) =>
        {
            Control?.ClearFocus();
            builder = null;
        });
        Android.Views.View view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview, null);
        Android.Widget.ListView listView = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(items, Element.SelectedIndex);
        listView.Adapter = myAdapter;
        listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;
        builder.SetView(view);
        listDialog = builder.Create();
        listDialog.Window.DecorView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Pink); // set the dialog background color 
        listDialog.Show();
        Android.Widget.Button button = listDialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative);
        button.Text = "Cancel";
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        button.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue); // set the button bottom color
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listDialog.Dismiss();
        listDialog = null;
    }

    private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Control.Text = items[e.Position];
        Element.SelectedIndex = e.Position;
        listDialog.Dismiss();
        listDialog = null;
    }

    class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private string[] items;
        private int selectedIndex;

        public MyAdapter(string[] items)
        {
            this.items = items;
        }

        public MyAdapter(string[] items, int selectedIndex) : this(items)
        {
            this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        }

        public override int Count => items.Length;

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return items[position];
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_item, null);
            }
            TextView textView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            textView.Text = items[position];
            return convertView;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
    <Picker x:Name="picker"  Title="Title" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Option 1</x:String>
                <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
                <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
```

**listview.xml**: You could creat in your `Resources/layout` in android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_item.xml** : You could creat in your `Resources/layout` in android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]